# Synonym suggestion - SSRS and reporting-services

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Is this the proper place to suggest a synonym? Specifically [reporting-services](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reporting-services) pointing to [ssrs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssrs)

Justification: SSRS is the acronym of SQL Server Reporting Services.

Comment: This is the proper place, however I'm not entirely sure that the synonym is 100% justified, can you give us an edit that explains why?

Comment: But is [tag:reporting-services] always guaranteed to be used for [tag:ssrs] forever?

Comment: No more than [tag:analysis-services] is guaranteed to be used for [tag:ssas] forever, or that Microsoft's SQL Server will be the only vendor to produce something people will refer to as [tag:sql-server] (even today, look how many people tag something MySQL and sql-server or sybase and sql-server).

Comment: I don't have a opinion - just noticed they weren't already synonyms.  But to follow @AaronBertrand, I would think `analysis-services` and `ssas` would be synonyms if these were.

Comment: I'm still wary of "let's lump them all together because of the assumption of a common name by Microsoft (or Oracle)". I understand the desire, but I can't see it as "the correct thing to do". This is why we have retagging tools, and edit tools. Feel free to edit and retag as you see fit.

Comment: Fair enough - agreed.

Comment: FYI - I just noticed that this is an established synonym on SO... Not that we must do the same, but I did want to mention it.  Same for SSAS and SSIS too.